# webdriver java. Large webtable, how to make finding a specific value fast

Tags: java, selenium

On a very large webtable, typically hundreds of rows and many columns, how can we make it fast to find a particular value? Ideally I want to specify a column name, look for cell data only for that column and retrieve a specified cell value.

My code is slow, it picks up all the data from all the cells in the table and then verifies each one of them to find the specified value. This consumes considerable amount of time.

```
public static void selectColumnValue(String tableXpath, String columnValue){ 
     String str, found = "false";
    // String colValue = null;
     WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(tableXpath));       
     List<WebElement> rows=table.findElements(By.xpath(tableXpath+"/tbody/tr"));
     for(WebElement row:rows)
     {
         List<WebElement> cols =row.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
         for(WebElement col:cols)
         {
             str=col.getText().trim();
             //System.out.println(str);
             if(str.matches(columnValue))
             {
                 //List<WebElement> vals=row.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
                 col.click();
                 found="true";

             }
         }
         if(found.matches("true")){
             break;
         } } }
```

HTML for a couple of rows is as below:

```
    <table id="T536870949" class="BaseTable" title="" style="top: 16px;">
<colgroup cols="5">
<col style="width: 139px;"/>
<col style="width: 140px;"/>
<col style="width: 139px;"/>
<col style="width: 140px;"/>
<col style="width: 119px;"/>
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr class="hiddentablehdr">
<th scope="col">Device Name</th>
<th scope="col">Site ID</th>
<th scope="col">Monitoring SSA</th>
<th scope="col">Manufacturer</th>
<th scope="col">Model</th>
</tr>
<tr class="" arrow="0" tabindex="0">
<td class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText" scope="row" style="width: 139px;" title="001000">
<nobr class="dp " style="text-align: right; width: 139px;">
</td>
<td class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText" style="width: 140px;">
<nobr class="dp " style="text-align: right; width: 140px;">
<span style="float:left;">NTA001</span>
</nobr>
</td>
<td class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText" style="width: 139px;" title="0019839">
<nobr class="dp " style="text-align: right; width: 139px;">
<span style="float:left;">0019839</span>
</nobr>
</td>
<td class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText" style="width: 140px;">
<nobr class="dp " style="text-align: right; width: 140px;">
<span style="float:left;">unknown</span>
</nobr>
</td>
<td class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText" style="width: 119px;">
</tr>
<tr class="" arrow="1" tabindex="0">
<td class="BaseTableCell BaseTableCellColor BaseTableStaticText" scope="row" style="width: 139px;" title="001001">
<nobr class="dp " style="text-align: right; width: 139px;">
<span style="float:left;">001001</span>
</nobr>
</td>
<td class="BaseTableCell BaseTableCellColor BaseTableStaticText" style="width: 140px;" title="001">
<nobr class="dp " style="text-align: right; width: 140px;">
<span style="float:left;">001</span>
</nobr>
</td>
<td class="BaseTableCell BaseTableCellColor BaseTableStaticText" style="width: 139px;" title="0019839">
<nobr class="dp " style="text-align: right; width: 139px;">
<span style="float:left;">0019839</span>
</nobr>
</td>
<td class="BaseTableCell BaseTableCellColor BaseTableStaticText" style="width: 140px;">
<nobr class="dp " style="text-align: right; width: 140px;">
<span style="float:left;">DMI</span>
</nobr>
</td>
<td class="BaseTableCell BaseTableCellColor BaseTableStaticText" style="width: 119px;">
<nobr class="dp " style="text-align: right; width: 119px;">
<span style="float:left;">Manufacturer=xyz</span>
</nobr>
</td>
</tr>

........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search for the full xpath of the element you are interested in, rather than looping in all elements, e.g.:

```
 String searchedXpath = tableXpath + "/tbody/tr/td[span='" + columnValue + "']/span";
 try {
     WebElement col = driver.findElement(By.xpath(searchedXpath )); 
     System.out.println("Value Found: " + col.getText());
 } 
 catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
     System.out.println("No such value in the table");
 }
```

of course condition [span='" + columnValue + "'] can be adjusted to whatever you think is correct (can be for instance [contains(span,columnValue)] )

Comment: Or even: `driver.findElement(By.xpath(tableXpath + "/tbody/tr/td[.='" + columnValue + "']")).click()`, which would match the OP's goal directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much (if at all) this will speed up your code, but I have written it exactly as per your ideal requirement where you give Column name and retrieve data from that column. I have written it for a table found on w3school. You may alter it accordingly for you table.

```
public class SimpleTests {
public static WebDriver driver;
public static String implicitwait="1";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    openBrowser();
    navigate("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp");
    String columnValue = "94";
    int columIndex = columnNum("Points"); // get column index.
    int numOfRow = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr")).size(); // get total number of rows


    boolean found = false;
    //for each row starting from 2nd, check your column for desired value.
    int i=2;
    for(;i<numOfRow;i++){
        WebElement columVals = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+columIndex+"]"));
        String tmp = columVals.getText();
        if (tmp.equals(columnValue)){
            found = true;
            break;
        }       
    }
    System.out.println("Element found: "+found+" > with xpath: "+"//tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+columIndex+"]");
    driver.quit();
}

public static int columnNum (String column){
    column = "Points";
    List<WebElement> FstRow = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/th"));
    int i = 1;
    for(WebElement element : FstRow){
        String tmp = element.getText();
        if (!tmp.equals(column)){
            i++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

public static void openBrowser(){       
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/FF16/firefox.exe");
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("capability.policy.default.Window.QueryInterface", "allAccess");  
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("capability.policy.default.Window.frameElement.get","allAccess");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    long implicitWaitTime=Long.parseLong(implicitwait);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(implicitWaitTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public static void navigate(String mmpUrl){     
    driver.navigate().to(mmpUrl);
}
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: @HusamI tried this after altering to my needs, but did not bring any improvement to speed. It could just be the way my page works...more investigation. But thanks for sharing the knowledge.